# $db->fetch_array() causes 500 error?

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am trying to make a vBulletin modification, and am having an issue where one command is causing a 500 error.

The line that has the issue is the `$db->fetch_array($result)` command. The entire code is below:

```
$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `".TABLE_PREFIX."user` WHERE `ipaddress` = '$ip'"; 
$result = $vbulletin->db->query($sql); 

$array = $db->fetch_array($result); 

while($array = $db->fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $unames[] = $row; 
} 

$userips = implode(',',$unames);
```

In vBulletin, `$vbulletin->db->fetch_array()` calls `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`.

I have a feeling that the error is in my SQL statement, but I cannot see why. Please could someone take a look? I've lost many hours over this error...

Answer (score 0):

```
   /** 
    *  Enable PHP Error Reporting
    *   - Use this in case of Page 500 Error to
    *     display Fatal/Warnings
    *
    *   - Dont use in live use.
   **/
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);

   /**
    *  Query
   **/
   $sql = "SELECT 
              `username` 
           FROM 
             `". TABLE_PREFIX ."user` 
           WHERE 
             `ipaddress` = '". $ip ."'"; 

   $result = $vbulletin->db->query_read($sql); 


   /**
    *  For each row, append ino dynamic array
    *     - Might need to set MYSQL_ASSOC
    *
    *  Although this might be:
    *     - $row = $vbulletin->db->fetch_array($result)
   **/
   while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
       $unames[] = $row; 
   } 

   /**  
    *  Stringify
   **/
   $userips = implode(',',$unames);
```

As `$vbulletin->$db` is it's own class, you can see their own [Documentation](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=119350) where it might be `query_read()` instead of `$db->query`